# Not getting sharp image of rectangles on canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, screenshot

I am parsing a .sym extension font file to get the character shapes. Characters are to made using pixels and hence this font file contains information in such form that it shows which pixel is to be shown in black color and which is not be colored.

I have written logic to draw these pixels using Rectangles on a WPF canvas and everything works fine except for the fact that I am not getting a sharp image. 
[image: Screenshot of the image of the canvas]

The purpose ultimately is to take the screenshot of this image of this canvas and paste wherever the user wants it to be pasted hence very clear image is required.

Also, when this image is exported in XPS and zoomed in, I get a very sharp image like below and hence I don't think there is any problem with the character making logic:

[image: Clear image when canvas exported in XPS]

I don't understand why this mismatch in clarity is happening.

Comment: Actually you are getting a very sharp image, what I think you want is aliasing (in Windows this is called ClearType). Because you are using "boxes" for pixels, your edges *look* jagged, but really they are very crisp and true to the underlying box. For the most part this is happening because your "pixel" is larger than a physical pixel on the display.

Comment: I have updated the question to add more details. When I export canvas in XPS then I get a very sharp image as shown in screenshot 2, then why I don't get a clear image in canvas itself. Because when I take a screenshot of canvas and zoom in, the image quality degrades to a greater extent.

Comment: *"draw these pixels using Rectangles on a WPF canvas"* Far better would be to use a WriteableBitmap, which could then be scaled usig different BitmapScalingModes.